# Floodfill not working also Mat.get(col,row) is returning wrong color

Tags: java, android, opencv, bmp, flood-fill

the floodfill is not effecting the bitmap also the Mat.get(col,row) is returning wrong color.

Things I have done:
a) checked that bitmap and matrix are of same size.
2) checked the color both ways RGB and BGR.
3) checked the initial bmp and final bmp (after applying flood fill).
4) checked floodfill with both signatures

```
public void flood(int x,int y,int sourceColor,int newColor){
    try {
        Bitmap bmp;
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
            image = new Mat();
            mat1 = new Mat();
            Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp2,mat1);
            image = Mat.zeros(mat1.rows()+2,mat1.cols()+2,CvType.CV_8U);
            if(bmp2.getWidth()==mat1.cols()){}
        }
        int k = mat1.channels();
        int col = bmp2.getPixel(x, y);
        int alpha = col & 0xFF000000;
        int red = (col & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        int green = (col & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        int blue = (col & 0x000000FF);
        double[] tt = (mat1.get(x,y));
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat1,mat1,Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
        tt = (mat1.get(x,y));

        //Imgproc.floodFill(mat1,image,p1,new Scalar(blue,green,red),new Rect(),new Scalar(230),new Scalar(220),4 + (255<<8) + Imgproc.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY);
        Imgproc.floodFill(mat1,image,p1,new Scalar(255,255,255));
        Core.subtract(image, Scalar.all(0), image);
        Rect roi = new Rect(1, 1, mat1.cols() - 2, mat1.rows() - 2);
        Mat temp = new Mat();

        image.submat(roi).copyTo(temp);
        mat1 = temp;
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat1.cols(),mat1.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mat1,bmp);
                }catch(CvException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
}
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mat.get(col,row) how do you know that? what does get(int, int) in the Mat class do? what result do you expect? What result do you get? ... ?

Comment: Hi @Stultuske I tapped on the yellow part of picture and it is supposed to return me yellow color but instead it is returning some shade of purple.

Comment: can you show us the code of Mat, have you debugged this (at all) ? what you tapped on is not necessarily related to the variables that are passed

Comment: Starting 5 lines in the try catch block are the lines where matrix are being created and yes i have debugged, but I can't understand why it isn't working

Comment: again, this says nothing about what the Mat class contains/does. I was asking about the code in Mat.java